# Get data from user control since Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a simple question in asp.net.
I want to know if it is possible to get data from controls in my user control directly . I want to do it without using Session variable,Viewstate ...

EDIT: I now use the method of declaring public variables in the UC.

Here is a part of Page_load from my parent page:

```
 this.plan_action = (UCPlan)Page.LoadControl("~/Association/UCPlan.ascx");
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(this.plan_action);

 if (this.plan_action.Validate == true)
        {
            CheckBox1.Checked = true;
            //String référence = Session["liste_action"].ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.plan_action.List1.Count; i++)
            {
                Label8.Text += this.plan_action.List1[i].Référence + "/";
                //Label8.Text += "/";
            }


        }
```

but my variable validate stay to false.

Here is the code where I change the value of the validate variable with it declaration:

```
    private bool validate;

    public bool Validate
    {
        get { return validate; }
        set { validate = value; }
    }


 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {


          //myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
          //Session["liste_action"] = this.List;
          this.Validate = true;
          //Response.Redirect("../Risques_folder/AjouterRisque.aspx");


      }
```

Thank you for your help,

Quentin

Comment: using the ID of your custom control, you can access all the public member of it. If you won to get text from textcontrol for example you make an extra variable that return this control.

Comment: u mean get data on server or on client??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** due to new information

You need to learn about the [sequence of events in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

The `Load` of the page happens a long time before the `Click` handler of `Button2` in your UserControl... so the `Validate` property is always going to be set to `false`.

You have two obvious options (as I see it)...

Keep the creation of the `UserControl` in your `Page_Load` (or preferably, move it to your `Page_Init`, as this is normally the most appropriate place for it).  Then place your check for the `Validate` property in a `Page_PreRender`.

Or, create an `Event` in your `UserControl`, `Raise` that event on the click of Button2, and handle the event in the Page.

---

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

For the 2nd of the two options above, in your `UserControl` class have the following...

```
public delegate void ButtonClickedDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ButtonClickedDelegate ButtonClicked;
```

In the `Button2_Click` method of the `UserControl` (**after** setting the `this.Validate = true;`) call...

```
ButtonClickedDelegate(sender, e);
```

In the `Page_Init` of the `Page`, put something like...

```
ctrl1.ButtonClicked += new UCPlan.ButtonClickedDelegate(ctrl1_ButtonClicked);
```

And then have a new method called something like

```
void ctrl1_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ctrl1.Validate)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Remember, as you control the `delegate` you can pass whatever information you want, including an entire class.  So instead of calling the `Validate` property, create a new instance of the class you want, and pass that as a delegate parameter.

You can find more information on [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN.

---

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Unless I've missed something, this is a very simple ASP.NET concept...

You can create properties and/or methods.

For example, as a property...

```
public string MyProperty
{
  get { return "My Property Value"; }
}
```

Or as a method

```
public string MyMethod()
{
   return "My Method Value";
}
```

---

**If you're talking about passing the values between the `UserControl` and the ASP.NET `Page` that contains it**, then in your `Page`, you can simply call the property or method.  If your control was called (for example) `myCtrl`, then you can something like...

```
string prop = myCtrl.MyProperty;
string meth = myCtrl.MyMethod();
```

---

(On the back of the great comment from  AHMED EL-HAROUNY)
**If you're talking about passing the values to the client side page**, then you can use the same properties / methods directly in the HTML markup.  However, in this case, the properties / method can be declared as `protected` rather than `public`

For instance, to display the value...

```
<%=MyProperty%>
```

Or

```
<%=MyMethod()%>
```

Or if you're going to use the value in javascript, something like...

```
var myProp = "<%=MyProperty%>";
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried this solution but it doesn't seems to work.In fact, when I click on a specific control in my UC a boolean variable pass to true in an event.After this,I test this variable on my webpage but it stays to false.

Comment: Are you sure of the correct sequence? Is the variable being set by the `event` *after* being checked in the page? Have you set breakpoints? (Sorry, these are probably silly questions, but I have to ask!)

Comment: You need to learn about the [sequence of events in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). The `Load` on the page will happen way before the click handler for Button2. I would suggest creating an `Event` within your control, assigning a dynamic handler for it in your `Page`

Comment: @Quentin, I have to go out for an hour... if you reply, I'm not ignoring you!

Comment: Yes, I am trying to implement a solution with delegate and event.For now, it's not working.If you have piece of code about this I 'd appreciate.

Comment: @Quentin, I have updated my answer with code example.  I cannot afford to spend any more time helping you. Hope what I have provided is helpful to you (and in return you will tick / mark my answer)

Comment: Just a little question about your code.What is ctrl1? Thank you again.

Comment: @Quentin, not a problem - it's just a made up name for the instance of the `UserControl` object

Answer (score 1):

Yes That is possible, But exposing the controls in the UserControl as **Public**.